# How can I activate a game bought from the Mac App Store on Steam?

Tags: steam, civilization-5, mac-app-store

If *Civilization 5* was bought from the Mac App Store, would I be able to activate it on Steam, and how could I do so?

It says [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601) that CD keys for *Civ 5* are accepted on Steam.  Would this still work for if that game was bought on the Mac App Store?  Does Apple's DRM allow compatibility with this other system or is there something that the developer of that game does to allow activation of that game on Steam?

I will accept "No" as an answer to this question because I am not sure myself if this is possible.

Comment: I thought Steam had an option to scan for non-steam games on the hard drive?

Comment: @CyberSkull You can add shortcuts to non-steam games from within steam, but you can't officially add them to steam (in the sense that steam recognizes it as a game and will handle updates or let you download it or other steam functions) unless they are officially supported and you have a CD-Key. I believe launching a non-steam game does give you the steam overlay, but I'm not 100% sure on that one (especially for the Mac version)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

To activate a game on Steam that you purchased from a third party, two things need to happen:

1. You must be provided with a CD key from the third-party retailer.
2. It must be [a game for which Steam accepts third-party CD keys](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-WUSF-3601).

When you buy a game (or any other software) on the Mac App Store, you aren't provided with a CD key, since the MAS itself handles product activation. (Apple's requirement is that all software sold on the MAS uses Apple's activation methods. CD keys and the like are disallowed.)

Answer (score 14):

After contacting the developer with proof of purchase from the Mac App Store, they gave me a Steam key, allowing me to activate the game on Steam.

Comment: What did you have to do to show proof of purchase?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to original question is 'Yes.'
When you purchase through the Mac Games Store, keys are provided.  These keys work on Steam. I just tried it.

Comment: Ford Prefect, where do you find this key?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Games` menu there should be an option for `Activate a product on Steam`. Enter the code into there, and it should automagically add the game. [source](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5414-TFBN-1352)

As pointed out, I am not familiar with the MAS. If you have no CD key, then it appears you have bought the Mac-only "Campaign Edition" version of Civ 5, which can not be linked to Steam. [source](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111004020034AASUmKb)

Comment: As with the previously deleted answer, it sounds like you're not familiar with the Mac App Store *which does not generate a code or product key.*